# About dual space and linear functional

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning, dual-spaces

Definition: For a vector space V over F, we define the dual space of V to be the vector space L(V,F), denoted by $V^*$.

Question: does that mean dual space is a set of linear functionals?

Comment: No, it means the *elements* / vectors of the dual space are the linear functionals.

Comment: The dual space is a (the) set of linear functionals; it is unclear whether this is what you're trying to say

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes, i was trying to say that.

Comment: In fact, the dual space is not merely “a” set of linear functionals, it is the set of *all* linear functionals on $V$.